# Collision for an Array of bricks and making a grid of bricks without using a 2D array for Processing

Tags: java, processing

I'm very new to processing and for a project in college we need to make an animation or game of some sort. I have chosen to make breakout for my animation but I am having problems with 2 parts of my code. The first one is that I am trying to get the bricks to line up across the top of the screen in a 5 by 6 grid. I got a little help from my lecturer but it only makes 2 rows and I think the rest of them go off screen. The second problem I'm having is trying to get hit detection to work for my ball and bricks. I think it's because the bricks are in an array and not a single object and I have no clue how to go about it. Any help or advice would be much appreciated. Below is what I have done so far.

**Main Code**

```
PImage bg;
PlayerName pl;
Ball bl;
Paddle pad;
Brick[] bricks;
int numOfCols = 30; // Number of bricks I want in total
int distRows = 1; // The distance between each of the bricks below each other

void setup() {
  size(1280, 720);
  noCursor();
  bg = loadImage("space.jpg");
  pl = new PlayerName(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your name (max of 12 char): "));
  bl = new Ball(51);
  pad = new Paddle(300,15);
  // Below is my attempt to try make the bricks spawn across the screen but it only does 2 rows
  bricks = new Brick[numOfCols];
  int xForBrick = 0;
  for(int col = 0; col < numOfCols; col++){
    if(col == 5)
    {
      distRows = 15;
      xForBrick = 0;
    }
    bricks[col] = new Brick(xForBrick*256,distRows);
    xForBrick++;
    
   }
   
  }
  


void draw() {
  background(bg);
   // Ignore these values below. This was just to help me visual stuff for hit detection.
  //text(pl.getName(),500,500);
  text(pad.getYPos(), 500,500);
  text(pad.getXPos(), 525,525);
  text(bl.getXCoord(), 500, 550);
  text(bl.getYCoord(), 525, 575);
  bl.display();  //Dsiplays the ball
  bl.gameOver(); // Controls the balls movement and ends game if ball goes off screen
  pad.display(); // Displays the paddle
  pad.movement(); //Controls the movement of the paddle with the mouse
  
  for(int col = 0; col < numOfCols; col++){
  bricks[col].display();
  }
  
  boolean collision = onHit(pad,bl);
  if (collision == true){
    bl.bounce();
  }

  
  boolean collision2 = onHit2(bl,bricks);
    if(collision2 == true){
    bl.bounce();
  }
}


boolean onHit(Paddle pad, Ball bl){
  float ballDistanceX = abs(bl.getXCoord() - pad.getXPos() - pad.getPaddleW()/2);
  float ballDistanceY = abs(bl.getYCoord() - pad.getYPos());
  
  if(ballDistanceX > (pad.getPaddleW()/2 + bl.getSize()/2)){
    return false;
  }
  
  if (ballDistanceY > (pad.getPaddleH()/2)){
    return false;
  }
  
  return true;
}

boolean onHit2(Ball bl, Brick bricks){
    float ballDistanceX2 = abs(bl.getXCoord() - bricks.getXPos() - bricks.getSizeW()/2);
    float ballDistanceY2 = abs(bl.getYCoord() - bricks.getSizeH());
    
    if(ballDistanceX2 > (bricks.getSizeW() + bl.getSize()/2)){
      return false;
    }
    if(ballDistanceY2 > (bricks.getSizeH()/2)){
      return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Ball class**

```
public class Ball {
  private float xCoord, yCoord, size, veloX, veloY;

  Ball(float size) {
    setSize(size);
    death();
  }

  public boolean gameOver() {
    boolean lose = false;
    xCoord = xCoord + veloX;
    yCoord = yCoord + veloY;

    //When ball leaves screen, ball resets
    if (yCoord > height + size/2) {
      death();
      lose = true;
    }
    // Makes ball bounce off of right edge
    if (xCoord > width - size/2) {
      xCoord = width - size/2;
      veloX = veloX * -1;
    }
    //Makes ball bounce off of left edge
    if (xCoord < size/2) {
      xCoord = size/2;
      veloX = veloX * -1;
    }
    // Makes it so the ball bounces off the top edge
    if (yCoord <  size/2) {
      yCoord =  size/2;
      veloY = veloY * -1;
    }
    return lose;
  }

  public void display() {
    fill(120, 70, 200);
    noStroke();
    ellipse(xCoord, yCoord, size, size);
  }

  //Makes ball bounce off of paddle
  public void bounce() {
    veloY = veloY * -1;
    yCoord = yCoord + veloY;
  }

  //When ball goes off the bottom of the screen, it resets back to the center with a different velocity
  private void death() {
    xCoord = width/2;
    yCoord = height/2;
    veloX = 3;
    veloY = -3;
  }

  public float getXCoord() {
    return xCoord;
  }

  public float getYCoord() {
    return yCoord;
  }

  public float getSize() {
    return size;
  }

  public float getVeloX() {
    return veloX;
  }

  public float getVeloY() {
    return veloY;
  }

  public void setXCoord(float xCoord) {
    this.xCoord = xCoord;
  }

  public void setYCoord(float yCoord) {
    this.yCoord = yCoord;
  }

  public void setSize(float size) {
    if ((size >= 30) && (size <= 50)) {
      this.size = size;
    } else {
      this.size = 30;
    }
  }

  public void setVeloX(float veloX) {
    this.veloX = veloX;
  }

  public void setVeloY(float veloY) {
    this.veloY = veloY;
  }
}
```

**Brick class**

```
public class Brick{
  private float xPos,yPos,sizeW,sizeH;
  boolean isShown;
  
  Brick(float xPos, float yPos){
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;
    sizeW = 256;
    sizeH = 15;
  }
  
  public void display(){
    fill(#8F52EC);
    stroke(0);
    strokeWeight(2);
    rect(xPos, yPos, sizeW, sizeH);
  }
  
  
  
  public float getXPos(){
    return xPos;
  }
  
  public float getYPos(){
    return yPos;
  }
  
  public float getSizeW(){
    return sizeW;
  }
  
  public float getSizeH(){
    return sizeH;
  }
  
  public boolean getIsShown(){
    return isShown;
  }
  
  public void setXPos(float xPos){
    this.xPos = xPos;
  }
  
  public void setYPos(float yPos){
    this.yPos = yPos;
  }
  
  public void setSizeW(float sizeW){
    this.sizeW = sizeW;
  }
  
  public void setSizeH(float sizeH){
    this.sizeH = sizeH;
  }
}
```

**Paddle class**

```
public class Paddle{
  private float xPos, yPos, paddleH, paddleW;
  
  public Paddle(float paddleW, float paddleH){
    setPaddleW(paddleW);
    setPaddleH(paddleH);
    
    xPos = width/2;
    yPos = height - this.paddleH;
  }
  
  public void movement(){
    xPos = mouseX - paddleW/2;
    
    if (xPos < 0){
      xPos = 0;
    }
    if (xPos > (width - paddleW)){
      xPos = width - paddleW;
    }
  }
  
  public void display(){
    fill(#320048);
    noStroke();
    rect(xPos,yPos,paddleW,paddleH);
  }
  
  public float getXPos(){
    return xPos;
  }
  
  public float getYPos(){
    return yPos;
  }
  
  public float getPaddleW(){
    return paddleW;
  }
  
  public float getPaddleH(){
    return paddleH;
  }
  
  public void setXPos(float xPos){
    this.xPos = xPos;
  }
  
  public void setYPos(float yPos){
    this.yPos = yPos;
  }
  
  public void setPaddleW(float paddleW){
    if ((paddleW >= 30) && (paddleW <= width/2)){
      this.paddleW = paddleW;
    }
    else {
      this.paddleW = 300;
    }
  }
  
  public void setPaddleH(float paddleH){
    if ((paddleH >= 10) && (paddleH <= 20)){
      this.paddleH = paddleH;
    }
    else {
      this.paddleH = 15;
    }
  }
}
```

**PlayerName class**

```
public class PlayerName{
  private String name;
  
  public PlayerName(String name){
    if(name.length() < 12){
      this.name = name;
    }
    else{
      this.name = name.substring(0,12);
    }
  }
  
  public String getName(){
    return name;
  }
  public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name.substring(0,12);
  }
}
```

Comment: That is a ton of code.  Please compile a [mre].  That does **NOT** mean strip the post down to only "relevant" code.  What I mean is, start a completely new project, add functionality until the problem shows up, and then post that new project, where the problem is isolated from the rest of your code.

Comment: You obviously put a lot of work into this project, but the format of your question makes it hard for us to both help you and future users (which are the real audience here). The comment which urges you to read and apply the guidelines isn't gatekeeping, I assure you. This community is very helpful, but we're committed to also help future users who will have similar issues and find your question through searches. By improving your question, you'll both make it easier for us to help and for the posterity to learn from your experience. Tag me when you edit your question, I'll be happy to help.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong Thank you so much, I'll remember that for when I seek future help. I think I'll just use the backup game I had already made a week after the assignment was given and submit that. I only decided to make breakout because I thought it would be interesting to give it a go.

Comment: @laancelot Thanks for responding. But if you wouldn't mind how should I go about formatting my question? Should I just make it shorter and straight to the point? Or is there like a certain way to go about it, if you don't mind me asking.

Comment: @Meticulous First thing, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) that you overlooked at first. It'll be a great introduction to SO's general culture. I know that visiting the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) doesn't sound very glamour, but it's a really good resource whenever you wonder if you're doing the right thing.

Comment: @Meticulous  I personally especially like [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). These are the most important resources you should consult to get used to what's expected of you when you ask a question.

Comment: @Meticulous What Charlie Armstrong said is paramount: this isn't a code review service, so when asking a question, having a minimal and reproducible example makes it more likely that the general principle behind your question is obvious, which makes it potentially usable not only for you but for anyone with a similar issue. A good trick is to present your questions as if you were asking a friendly professional with very little time to give: complete, straight to the point, clear question and no pollution from unrelated stuff. The other details are all addressed in the previous links.

Comment: @laancelot Thank you so much, I appreciate it. I'll look over the links in your comments and I'll know better for next time. Thanks for the friendly responses too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see everything, but try this change in main:

```
int xForBrick = 0;
for(int col = 0; col < numOfCols; col++)
{
    if(col %  5 == 0) //change here
    {
        distRows = distRows + 1; //change here
        xForBrick = 0;
    }
    bricks[col] = new Brick(xForBrick*256,distRows);
    xForBrick++;
}
```